# creating desktop application self service kiosk using wordpay in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, worldpay

I am developing desktop application I have written the backend code need to know how to get that token parameter and another thing in my case it will be self-service kiosk like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neBgllAvOWY how I will get credit card details to for transaction in a desktop application.

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        Worldpay.Sdk.WorldpayRestClient restClient = new 

        Worldpay.Sdk.WorldpayRestClient("https://api.worldpay.com/v1", "T_S_11cca65b-c15a-467c-8561-35ecfa07725b");



       var orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
        {
            amount = 1999,
            currencyCode = CurrencyCode.GBP.ToString(),
            name = "Joe Bloggs",
            orderDescription = "Order description",
            token = "T_C_9feb32e6-eac0-4345-bba0-3319d1ddbe1f"
        };

        var address = new Address()
        {
            address1 = "line 1",
            address2 = "line 2",
            city = "city",
            countryCode = CountryCode.GB.ToString(),
            postalCode = "AB1 2CD"
        };

        orderRequest.billingAddress = address;


        try
        {
            OrderResponse orderResponse = restClient.GetOrderService().Create(orderRequest);
            MessageBox.Show("Order code: " + orderResponse.orderCode);
        }
        catch (WorldpayException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error code:" + er.apiError.customCode);
            MessageBox.Show("Error description: " + er.apiError.description);
            MessageBox.Show("Error message: " + er.apiError.message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done chip and pin integration.
The payment provider usually has a small app or service on the pc which communicates with the chip and pin device.
Your app communicates with that.

The process i wrote was fairly complicated using asynchronous communication over sockets.
It's way more than you just tell it to pay 10 quid and it says ok.

Comment: so i need to write code to communicative with that chip .can you please tell the documentation about it

Comment: You (usually) communicate with an application your payment provider has. They're  the one to ask about that. Chip and pin (device) integration is completely different from web based payments.

Comment: i want to use it for desktop application dont know how deduction of money form device will notify the desktop application to print success message like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neBgllAvOWY